# Loader(spinner.js) shows after the calculations are done, even though its called first

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that performs some calculations. It takes a while for it to finish, so I would like to show a "waiting bar" or spinner to the user, while it calculates. However, this doesn't work. It doesn't matter whether I write

```
<button onclick="showSpinner();performCalculations();hideSpinner();">
```

or

```
function performCalculations()
{
    showSpinner();
    [performCalculations...]
    hideSpinner();
}
```

and then

```
<button onclick="performCalculations();">
```

It's as if JavaScript makes a note that is has to show the spinner once all the calculations are done, performs the calculations, and then shows and hides the spinner!

I have this vague idea that this has something to do with timing, and I fear that what I want may not at all be possible with JavaScript. Like for instance showing a running output of a running function - I know that's impossible. Is this the same thing?

I don't suppose I should use setTimeout or setInterval - I don't want to waste the user's time.

I've tried to implement spin.js, but I can't make it work.

I really apologize if this question has been asked before - I've tried to search for it, but I can't find anything that resembles my question.

Comment: How are showSpinner/hideSpinner implemented? It would help to create a jsfiddle too

Comment: Sounds like an ideal job for [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage)...

Comment: I tried to use this: http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/ - but if I call the spin() method, nothing happens. But that's perhaps because nothing happens until everything is finished...?

Comment: I agree, sounds like an ideal job for web workers

Comment: You can see the script in action on http://silicium.dk/modelrocketsimulator/ - on the launch button, I call showSpinner() before launch(), and hideSpinner() afterwards.

Comment: Never heard of web workers. Is it as complicated as it sounds? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Nicholas Zakas once said:

> The browser UI thread is responsible for both UI updates and
>   Javascript execution.... Only one can happent at a time

**EDIT:**
 I initially thought the spinner function wasn't executed at once because they where delayed by timeouts, and that's a valid point and could happen, but the main culprit here is the js single thread, because not only timers are postponed and added to a later execution time queue, but the ui changes too, so there is a priority for js to complete all the code that does not make changes in the ui(pure js), in my example the loop, so it will complete this loop and then make changes to the ui. As you can see in the following timeline, the ui changes (purple and green) happens after the loop is done (yellow)

[image]

But if we add our loop to the execution queue via time out, it'll be executed after the ui changes, so this is probably the only fix in cases like this (that i can think of), check the next image and you can see the difference.

[image]

---

Well since it is a JavaScript spinner, internally it should be using setInterval, what this does is to add the function to a queue, by design, JavaScript executes first the code that is not in a timeout and when its done it goes to that queue and grabs what is there and executes it. So the easier solution for this is to use a css spinner, you just show and hide its div.

[Cleanest CSS spinner, ever](http://lea.verou.me/2013/11/cleanest-css-spinner-ever/)

Another solution could be to add a small timeout to the calculations.

```
function performCalculations()
{

    showSpinner();
    setTimeout(function(){
      [performCalculations...] 
      hideSpinner();
    }, 0);


}
```

**Here is a working jsfiddle, that proves this point and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/621tcqh6/3/**

Note: Sometimes you have to click twice to make the spinner appear, this seems to be an issue with jsFiddle and not the code itself, since i tested locally and that didn't happen

I should say that this is just a theory based on what i know, if you create a jsfiddle, i could test it. Hope it helps to understand why is this happening.

Comment: Wouldn't this delay the calculations further? I'm already up to 13 seconds for some of the calculations, and that is only with 10 ms resolution - I would like to go to 1 ms resolution!

Comment: Not really, in neither case, you can put the delay to 0, the only effect that this will have is to add your calculations to the queue, so first your showSpinner, will go to that queue, then your calculations and then your hide spinner. But if you are really worried about speed you should use webworkers and split the work beteen them.

Comment: Even if this makes a delay, it will only be a neglible one after the click, if you want it to start faster, you should use onmousedown instead of onclick and yould could save up to 100mls.

Comment: I just tried to put the calculations inside a setTimeout - that didn't work either. I'd like to try and make a jsfiddle - I've never tried it before, but I'll try.

Comment: Fixed, the hideSpinner function should be inside the setTimeout, i assumed that it called its own setTimeout function, but it seems it uses css animations if avialable, so this should fix your code, if it works please vote as correct answer =)

Comment: thanks, it really working.. I takes almost half day to fix it.. thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If you could break up your calculations into individually executable bits, then you could use `setInterval` or `setTimeOut` so that your spinner gets a chance to do its stuff between those bits.

Comment: But setTimeout is used to call some function after a specified time has elapsed, which just adds a delay...? Why would I use setTimeout?

Comment: Oh, you mean I should call some function for every step of the calculation? (It's a simulation) Wouldn't I lose all the variable values?

Comment: Not if you store them somewhere that isn't local to your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you've posted.  Are you sure showSpinner() and hideSpinner() are functioning properly or perhaps your calculations are happening faster than you think?  Maybe try simplifying it by hiding and showing some text and further debug by replacing the calculations with a 5 second timeout for a predictable delay.

Thanks for posting link to page.  I don't have a full explanation since I didn't look at the details of the spinner or launch code but possibly a solution.  When you call

```
spinner.spin(target)
```

target is sometimes null.  I believe this is because you're defining target before the document is loaded.  Since I see jQuery on your page you can put the initilizations in [$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) 
.  Or just change

`spinner.spin(target)`

to

```
spinner.spin(document.getElementById('container'));
```

After that try sticking spinner.stop() inside your launch() function at the end of it.

Like I said, doesn't explain everything but I have a feeling it will give you the desired affect.

Comment: You can see it on http://silicium.dk/modelrocketsimulator/ - if you choose a D12-3 engine, the simulation takes 13 seconds.